# After changing the value in input tag auto simulate Enter Key

Tags: javascript, html, triggers, dom-events

I am entering data into a hidden input tag in HTML using JavaScript. I am able to do that but I need to simulate <kbd>ENTER</kbd> Key on keyboard to pass data into database, but the Problem in could not simulate the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I have tried bunch of solutions on events, listener and DOM, but none of them worked for me.

I am using DynamoDB to so it doesn't matter what type of data we enter or how; some of the code I have tried is:

```
function enter1() {
  var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
  delete keyboardEvent.which;
  var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? 'initKeyboardEvent' : 'initKeyEvent';
  keyboardEvent[initMethod](
    'keydown', // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
    true, // bubbles
    true, // cancelable
    window, // viewArg: should be window
    false, // ctrlKeyArg
    false, // altKeyArg
    false, // shiftKeyArg
    false, // metaKeyArg
    13, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
    13 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
  );
  document.getElementById('newdata').dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
}
```

I have tried various solutions provided using JavaScript, JQuery, events etc.
but none of them work.

```
<input  className="new" placeholder="add data " type="hidden"
id = "newdata" value="need to add to data base"  />
```

```
Wholevalue = " result1 = " + result1 + " Result2 = " + ressult2 + " result3 = " + result3 + "\n";
    alert(wholevalue);
    document.getElementById("newdata").setAttribute("value", wholevalue);
```

I look for a way when data is change /input into the value field via script, it detects <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, so it passes the data.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to trigger the change event yourself everytime you change the value. Once the change notification is received, you can dispatch a keypress for the Enter key.

I have given the code snippet below that triggers a value change event, which in turn triggers a keypress event.

Hope that helps.

```js
$('#hiddenValue').change(TriggerValueChanged);
$('#hiddenValue').keypress(HandleKeyPress);
  
$('#hiddenValue').val("value change 1").trigger('change');
$('#hiddenValue').val("value change 2").trigger('change');
  
function TriggerValueChanged(element) {
  var event = $.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );
  $('#hiddenValue').trigger(event);
}
  
function HandleKeyPress(event) {
  if(event.which == 13) {
    alert(`KeyPress Detected. Event.Which: ${event.which}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenValue" value="" />
```